# Topology/Space of Recursive Algebraic Datatypes

Tags: ds.data-structures, functional-programming, topology

I have a recursive algebraic datatype. I (somewhat arbitrarily) defined one function to compute distance between instances, and am trying to define a function to approximate a "vector" between instances.  I assume there's no single way to define a metric space on top of a definition of an algebraic data type, much less a vector space, but was wondering what literature exists about treating recursive algebraic datatypes as existing in a topological space with meaningful comparisons.

The reason I want to treat it like a vector space is because I want to define interpolation between two structures in some reasonable manner.

Comment: What do you need these structures for? That might direct possible choices in a useful way. They yearning for vectors makes it look like you're secretly doing machine learning.

Comment: Haha, I do come from something of a machine learning background, so maybe that shows through!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to construct recursive datatypes (algebraic datatypes are a special case) in a suitable category of complete metric spaces, see for instance P. America and J. Rutten's [Solving Reflexive Domain Equations in a Category of Complete Metric Spaces](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~janr/papers/files-of-papers/1989-JCSS.pdf), Journal of Computer and System Sciences 39, 343-375 (1989).

As for making vector spaces out of algebraic datatypes, I do not really know, but if you explain what you want them for, we might be able to suggest something.